# What, if anything, do we need to do about separating questions about OpenSearch (circa 2005) versus OpenSearch (circa 2021)?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

According to Wikipedia, the 'original' OpenSearch was created in 2005:

> OpenSearch is a collection of technologies that allow the publishing of search results in a format suitable for syndication and aggregation. Introduced in 2005, it is a way for websites and search engines to publish search results in a standard and accessible format.

However, it also is the name recently given to the Amazon fork of Elasticsearch.  The GitHub project page for that can be found [here](https://github.com/opensearch-project) and general website https://opensearch.org/.  I assume it has more to do with trademarks or copyright since, as Amazon already owned them, it was free to use it for whatever, even if it meant redefining what 'OpenSearch' was.

While I am unsure of how much the 'original' OpenSearch gained traction, there is evidence that it is still getting legitimate questions asked as recently as last month ([Setting keyword entry in opensearch.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885209/setting-keyword-entry-in-opensearch-xml)).  Of the 94 questions are tagged with [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch), it appears all but four are for the original and are somewhat evenly spread from 2013 to 2020.  With such a big name fork, and the popularity of the [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) tag (~51K at the time of this writing), I would expect that the OpenSearch tag will significantly ramp up here, but more in the 'new' use of OpenSearch.

I am unsure if the community needs to take any action, or just let the ambiguity exist.  I can't easily think of what to rename the original OpenSearch tag to that wouldn't still be possibly confused with the new one.  The topics are pretty disparate, so users should be able to tell, but I find the tagging system to be useful and in general it seems like the disparate topics in the same tag are undesirable.  I wasn't able to find any precedent in the meta for an approach, but that may just be that I wasn't aware of a prior example and it was difficult to find.  Most of the ambiguities in  `tag-disambiguation` are examples of very generic names (or a category of thing) or two things that actually have different specific names getting lumped together.  In this case, we have two things that actually have the same specific name with different implementations.

Comment: Surely there's other past occurrences of this that we can use for precedence, for example, angular vs angularjs

Comment: I think that renaming this tag to something else (but I don't know what; maybe "opensearch-document" or "opensource-file-format"), and creating a new "opensource" tag specifically for the Amazon AWS project might be the way to go. Or burn it (remove it from existing questions) and repurpose it. Some of the links in the opensource wiki are broken, and even ones on pages that work are broken (in particular, any references to the "opensource.org" web site since it seems to have been redone).

Comment: I was thinking going in the other direction, amazon-opensearch for the new one, akin to amazon-ec2 and other aws related tags

Comment: @KevinB I was initially thinking that, too, but after looking into it some (Amazon owns the trademark and related web address) it seemed that not having "opensearch" refer to the Amazon project would lead to longer term confusion and related issues. The old "opensearch" seems to be dying/disappearing.

Comment: @KevinB I hadn't considered that, but even though I referred to it as the 'Amazon fork', which I think it technically is or at least appears that way (lots of Amazon.com addresses), I don't think it is their aim to be known as that.  The announcement (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-opensearch/) frames it as a community-driven fork and there really isn't any information on the project pages that would tell users that it was the 'amazon' fork, which may make it difficult for question askers in the future to realize that is the right tag.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I was actually quite surprised there were any questions even relatively recently on the old nomenclature.  I was expecting a much cleaner split between them and was thinking we could just add a note about the time before/after, in the tag description but the activity seemed to complicated that idea.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I like how you switch from opensearch to opensource in your first comment and then stick to it ... ;)

Comment: Inspiration could be taken from other abused words, like "unity" ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Enterprise_Library#Version_5.0_Silverlight_Integration_Pack), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)), and [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_Operating_System)).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Disclosure: I work for Amazon specifically on OpenSearch]

If you take a look at the [disambiguation page on OpenSearch.org](https://opensearch.org/disambiguation.html), it refers to the 2005 OpenSearch as the "OpenSearch Syndication Protocol" and the [still existing OpenSearch GitHub repo](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch) calls it the "OpenSearch Protocol."

The 2021 project itself doesn't use "Amazon OpenSearch," (rather specifically) just "OpenSearch" or "OpenSearch Project." It's open source & community driven and using "Amazon OpenSearch" would not be welcoming for non-Amazon contributors.

I'd propose:

[opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch) -> OpenSearch.org (2021)

[opensearch-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch-protocol) -> github.com/dewitt/opensearch (2005)

Comment: I touched base with Dewitt Clinton (of OpenSearch 2005). He doesn't do stack overflow, but he did [tweet](https://twitter.com/dewitt/status/1421198167941419013) on the issue.

Comment: Sadly, this still leaves us with a ambiguous tag: opensearch. While it makes total sense for the users of amazon project that opensearch is about the tool, it's not so for the ones that haven't heard of it. The best solution is to prevent ambiguity by being explicit in the naming.

Comment: The opensearch project isn't an Amazon project. It's an open source project - a cross-organisation fork of the formerly open source elasticsearch. As a non-amazon contributor, I'd be sad to see a single (admittedly currently the biggest by miles) contributor specified in a community-owned project.

Answer (score 18):

[One is a protocol](https://github.com/dewitt/opensearch), [the other is a product](https://github.com/opensearch-project/OpenSearch) (based on another product). Amazon's opensearch can be [amazon-opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-opensearch) meanwhile the other can be [opensearch-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch-protocol). That's how disambiguation goes, removing the ambiguous tag. People wouldn't be confused by either.

Answer (score -3):

Is it a problem *now*?

If so, then I would imagine that patterns of the problem or symptoms of the problem exist or are appearing, such as users tagging the question as [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch) when they actual mean to talk about Amazon's Elasticsearch variant.

If *not*, then there's not a lot of preemptive work to do in this case, since we don't know the convention we want others to follow.

It'd be good to tackle this when it's an actual issue as opposed to while it's a more theoretical issue, in my mind.

Comment: There are currently four questions that belong to the 'new' usage, with the others to the old.

Comment: ...but is it a *problem*?  Four questions sounds like ~10 minutes of editing work.  400+ sounds like a problem.

Comment: @makato I guess not, if you don't mind two different topics on the same tag.  However, that appears to be a anti-pattern on SO.  My experience has been that things are easier to fix at the beginning.  That being said, this was for discussion for the community to decide if they wanted two different, active topics under the same tag or not.  If not, then ok.  I just found the potential problem when I needed to file a question and raised the discussion here.

Comment: I guess we would like to see a more decisive answer on "Should we let two topics with the same name use the same tag?" If yes, then we need to take action, and it's better to do it asap, for which now is the best time, if not, then we don't need to take action. Saying "it's not a problem now" only defers the decision, no? But I guess your (Makoto) point here is "I think the two topics won't gain popularity enough for this to be a problem", for which I respectfully disagree, with the reasons laid out by Foghorn in the question body and in the latest comment above.

Comment: I agree with OP that we can and should do something before the problem begins. To give @Makoto a good example, imagine [tag:git] (popular tag) will be renamed to [tag:lit], you would definitely want to do something.

Comment: @justhalf:  I wasn't insinuating that there wouldn't be a rise in popularity in the topics.  I was more on the lines of, "Is this something that *requires* immediate action?"  I'm representing a very extreme position on this matter and I would like to hear a strong justification to take action this early in the game.  Historically, we've only really dealt with disambiguations that have become truly *problematic*, like the AngularJS vs Angular split and Python vs Python 3.

Comment: @Makoto I see your point of view, but I wonder if the angular example is because there conscious community consensus to let the mess happen and fix it later, or if it just wasn't identified as a problem for the community to decide.  It could have been intentional to leave it a mess for a while, but even if that was the case, I question if that is what *should* have happened.  In any case, I am happy to see the community having the discussion now including your point of view.

Answer (score -7):

We need to disambiguate the tag into names that are both specific enough *and antagonistic enough* that one wouldn't pick one when they need the other.

E.g.:

- [opensearch-original-2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch-original-2005)
- [opensearch-elasticsearch-2021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch-elasticsearch-2021)

Comment: Why the downvotes?