# Disambiguating the [opensearch] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Disclosure: I am working for AWS on the OpenSearch project.

This question is edging on being a duplicate of [What, if anything, do we need to do about separating questions about OpenSearch (circa 2005) versus OpenSearch (circa 2021)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410455/what-if-anything-do-we-need-to-do-about-separating-questions-about-opensearch) but I am posting it as a new question because at the time of the previous question, there was insufficient history to determine if a problem existed.  That question and the [highest voted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410482/1161484) gives excellent context for this retag request.  The OP in that question remarked:

> I would expect that the OpenSearch tag will significantly ramp up here, but more in the 'new' use of OpenSearch.

This expectation has proven accurate. At the time the previous question was posted, there were 94 questions tagged [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch).  Less than a year later, there are now 415.  A problem exists and some retagging/cleanup is needed among multiple related tags. The problem will only get worse if we put off the decision, which was apparently what happened a year ago.

Specific requests:

1. Questions currently tagged [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch) written prior to July 2021 should be retagged [opensearch-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch-protocol) as the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410482/1161484) to the previous question recommended.  (This was [supported in a tweet](https://web.archive.org/web/20210730195722/https://twitter.com/dewitt/status/1421198167941419013) by the current maintainer of the project the tag wiki refers to. To be clear, [Amazon owns the OpenSearch trademark](https://opensearch.org/disambiguation.html) and has chosen to change the branding to which it refers.)
2. The overwhelming majority of questions since August 2021 refer to [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/) and should be identified with the [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch) tag.

   - Since there still may be some disambiguation required, [opensearch-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch-project) may be appropriate for the "new" OpenSearch, with [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch) as an alias.
3. The [amazon-opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-opensearch) tag should be renamed [amazon-opensearch-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-opensearch-service) and cleaned up to retag any questions which are not related to the managed service to [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch).

   - While Amazon forked the open source version of ElasticSearch, they have made it clear from the beginning that it is a community project, so "Amazon OpenSearch" is not accurate.
4. The [amazon-elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-elasticsearch) and [aws-elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-elasticsearch) tags should be removed; questions should be appropriately retagged to either [amazon-opensearch-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-opensearch-service) (most of the questions), [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) or [opensearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opensearch).

   - In September 2021, Amazon [renamed their service](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-elasticsearch-service-is-now-amazon-opensearch-service-and-supports-opensearch-10/) in order to avoid infringing on Elastic's trademark.  Stack Overflow should be consistent with this trademark disambiguation and avoid implying that anybody other than Elastic owns ElasticSearch.

Comment: If we keep a tag that's just "opensearch", we're still going to have people using it for things that should be tagged with opensearch-protocol and amazon-opensearch-service. That still needs a name that distinguishes it from the other two.

Comment: @BSMP I'd be fine with `opensearch-project` with `opensearch` as an alias.

Comment: No, zero aliases. Aliases shouldn't exist when people will type one or the other. The tag picker is smart enough to show you every tag in order of popularity.

Comment: @Braiam then someone will just create it

Comment: And we just have to remove it again. If it becomes a problem we blacklist it. We do not leave ambiguous tags on the site just because "someone might create it"